# Wrong JPEG library - ruby on rails- OS X

Tags: ruby, macos, osx-snow-leopard, jpeg

I keep getting this error any time i call any page that has a call that uses RMagick, but i can't figure out what library i'm missing, or what i need to install to get rid of this error. Does anyone have debugging suggestions?

```
    Processing SimpleCaptchaController#simple_captcha (for 127.0.0.1 at 2010-01-14 14:24:24) [GET]
  Parameters: {"image_style"=>"", "time"=>"1263500664", "simple_captcha_key"=>"13eec13214d2ce84b725d14c5877fcbe13308cf5", "distortion"=>""}
Could not dump header data for exception: not opened for reading

ArgumentError (unknown format: JPG):
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/fiveruns-dash-ruby-0.8.10/lib/fiveruns/dash/instrument.rb:125:in `perform_action_without_rescue'
```

...

After re-installing based on this cache of the bellow attempted solution

i am getting this error:

```
Magick::ImageMagickError (Wrong JPEG library version: library is 62, caller expects 70 `' @ jpeg.c/EmitMessage/232):
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to:

```
sudo port uninstall jpeg
```

install image magic using this script on git:

http://github.com/masterkain/ImageMagick-sl

after i was able to install rmagick:

```
sudo gem install rmagick
```

now, no more problems.

Answer (score 1):

Their site is down at the moment, but when it comes back online you should run this install script by Solomon White.

http://onrails.org/articles/2009/09/04/rmagick-from-source-on-snow-leopard

Comment: That is how i installed everything from the beginning. It executed as expected, but I am still getting this error.

Comment: I attempted running the sh file again. I found a cache of the site...i am gettin a new error.